# extract unique block of lines from a file using shell script

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix

I am facing few problems while extracting block of lines from a file. consider following two files

```
File-1
1.20/abc/this_is_test_1
perl/RRP/RRP-1.30/JEDI/JEDIExportSuccess2
exec perl/RRP/RRP-1.30/JEDI/CommonReq/confAbvExp
perl/LRP/BaseLibs/close-MMM
exec perl/LRP/BaseLibs/launchLRPCHURRTA("TYRE")
this/or/that

File-2
exec 1.20/setup/testird
exec 1.20/sql/temp/Test3
exec 1.20/setup/testxyz
exec 1.20/sql/fondle_opr_sql_labels
exec 1.20/setup/testird
exec 1.20/sql/temp/NEWTest
exec 1.20/setup/testxyz
exec 1.20/sql/fondle_opr_sql_xfer
exec 1.20/setup/testird
exec 1.20/sql/set_sec_not_0
exec 1.20/setup/testpqr
exec 1.20/sql/sql_ba_statuses_on_mult
exec perl/RRP/SetupReq/testdef_ijk
exec perl/RRP/RRP-1.30/JEDI/SetupReq/confAbvExp
exec perl/RRP/RRP-1.30/JEDI/JEDIExportSuccess1
exec perl/RRP/SetupReq/testdef_ijk
exec perl/RRP/RRP-1.30/JEDI/SetupReq/confAbvExp
exec perl/RRP/RRP-1.30/JEDI/JEDIExportSuccess2
exec perl/RRP/SetupReq/testdef_ijk
exec perl/RRP/RRP-1.30/JEDI/SetupReq/confAbvExp
exec perl/RRP/RRP-1.30/JEDI/JEDIExportSuccess3
exec 1.20/setup/testird
exec 1.20/sql/sqlmenu_purr_labl
exec 1.20/sql/est_time_at_non_drp_plc
exec 1.20/sql/half_Brd_Supply_mix_single
exec 1.20/setup/testird
exec 1.20/sql/temp/Test
exec 1.20/setup/testird
exec 1.20/sql/temp/Test2
exec perl/LRP/SetupReq/testird_LRP("LRP")
exec perl/BaseLibs/launch_client("LRP")
exec perl/LRP/LRP-classic-4.14/churrip/chorSingle
exec perl/LRP/BaseLibs/setupLRPMMMTab
exec perl/LRP/BaseLibs/launchMMM
exec perl/LRP/BaseLibs/launchLRPCHURRTA("TYRE")
#PAUSE Expand Churrip tree view & open all nodes
exec perl/LRP/LRP-classic-4.14/Corrugator/multipleSeriesWeb
exec perl/BaseLibs/ShutApp("Self Destruction System")
exec perl/LRP/BaseLibs/close-MMM
exec 1.20/setup/testmiddle
exec 1.20/sql/collective_reads
exec 1.20/setup/testinit
exec 1.20/abc/this_is_test_1
exec 1.20/abc/this_is_test_1
exec perl/LRP/SetupReq/abcDEF
exec perl/BaseLibs/launch_client("sqlC","LRP")
exec perl/LRP/LRP-perl-4.20/fireTrigger
```

Now for every line in File-1 i want to extract relevant block of lines from File-2. 
A block in File-2 is defined as below

```
exec 1.20/setup/xxxxx
blah blah blah
blah blah blah
.
.
.
all lines till next setup line is found
```

for example

```
exec 1.20/setup/testinit
exec 1.20/abc/this_is_test_1
exec 1.20/abc/this_is_test_1
```

or

```
exec perl/LRP/SetupReq/xxxxx
blah blah blah
blah blah blah
.
.
.
all lines till next setup line is found
```

for example

```
exec perl/LRP/SetupReq/testird_LRP("LRP")
exec perl/BaseLibs/launch_client("LRP")
exec perl/LRP/LRP-classic-4.14/churrip/chorSingle
exec perl/LRP/BaseLibs/setupLRPMMMTab
exec perl/LRP/BaseLibs/launchMMM
exec perl/LRP/BaseLibs/launchLRPCHURRTA("TYRE")
#PAUSE Expand Churrip tree view & open all nodes
exec perl/LRP/LRP-classic-4.14/Corrugator/multipleSeriesWeb
exec perl/BaseLibs/ShutApp("Self Destruction System")
exec perl/LRP/BaseLibs/close-MMM
```

I have so far managed to extract relevant blocks from File-2 with help of following script

```
Shell Script
#set -x
FLBATCHLIST=$1
BATCHFILE=$2

TEMPDIR="/usr/tmp/tempBatchDir"
rm -rf $TEMPDIR/*

WORKFILE="$TEMPDIR/failedTestList.txt"
CPBATCHFILE="$TEMPDIR/orig.test"
TESTSETFILE="$TEMPDIR/testset.txt"
TEMPFILE="$TEMPDIR/temp.txt"
DIFFFILE="$TEMPDIR/diff.txt"

#Output
FAILEDBATCH="$TEMPDIR/FailedBatch.test"
LOGFILE="$TEMPDIR/log.txt"

createBatch ()
{

TESTNAME=$1
#First process the $CPBATCHFILE to not have any blank lines, leading and trailing whitespaces
# delete BOTH leading and trailing whitespace from each line and blank lines from file
sed -i 's/^[[:space:]]*//;s/[[:space:]]*$//g;/^$/d' $CPBATCHFILE
FOUND=0
STATUS=1
while [ $STATUS -ne "0" ]
do
        if [ ! -s $CPBATCHFILE ]; then
                echo "$CPBATCHFILE is empty" >> $LOGFILE
                STATUS=0
        fi
        awk '/[Ss]etup.*[Tt]est/ || /perl\/[[:alpha:]]*\/[Ss]etup[rR]eq/{if(b) exit; else b=1}1' $CPBATCHFILE > $TESTSETFILE
        grep -i "$TESTNAME$" $TESTSETFILE >> $LOGFILE 2>&1
        if [ $? -eq "0" ]; then
                echo "test found" >> $LOGFILE
                cat $TESTSETFILE >> $FAILEDBATCH
                FOUND=1
        fi
        TSTFLLINES=`wc -l < $TESTSETFILE`
        CPBTCHLINES=`wc -l < $CPBATCHFILE`
        DIFF=`expr $CPBTCHLINES - $TSTFLLINES`
        tail -n $DIFF $CPBATCHFILE > $DIFFFILE
        mv $DIFFFILE $CPBATCHFILE
done

if [ $FOUND -eq 0 ]; then
        echo $TESTNAME > $TEMPDIR/test.txt
        ABSTEST=$(echo $TESTNAME | sed 's/\\//g')
        echo "FATAL ERROR: Test \"$ABSTEST\" not found in batch" | tee -a $LOGFILE
fi

}

####STARTS HERE####
mkdir -p $TEMPDIR
#cat  $TEMPDIR/test.txt
#FLBATCHLIST="$TEMPDIR/test.txt"
# delete run, BOTH leading and trailing whitespace and blank lines from file
sed 's/^[eE][xX][eE][cC]//g;s/^[[:space:]]*//;s/[[:space:]]*$//g;/^$/d' $FLBATCHLIST > $WORKFILE

# escaping special characters like '\' and '.' in the path names for better grepping
sed -i 's/\([\/\.\"]\)/\\\1/g' $WORKFILE

for fltest in $(cat $WORKFILE)
do
        echo $fltest >> $LOGFILE
        cp $BATCHFILE $CPBATCHFILE
        createBatch $fltest
done

sed -i 's/\//\\/g' $FAILEDBATCH
## Clean up
cp $FAILEDBATCH .
```

THe problem with this script is

1. It takes some time as it traverses File-2 for each line of File-1. I wanted to know if there is any better solution where i just have to traverse File-2 once.
2. The script does solve my problem but I am left with file which has duplicate blocks of lines in it. I wanted to know is there a way to remove the duplicate blocks of lines.

This is my output when i execute the script

```
exec 1.20\setup\testinit
exec 1.20\abc\this_is_test_1
exec 1.20\abc\this_is_test_1
exec perl\RRP\SetupReq\testdef_ijk
exec perl\RRP\RRP-1.30\JEDI\SetupReq\confAbvExp
exec perl\RRP\RRP-1.30\JEDI\JEDIExportSuccess2
exec perl\RRP\SetupReq\testdef_ijk
exec perl\RRP\RRP-1.30\JEDI\SetupReq\confAbvExp
exec perl\RRP\RRP-1.30\JEDI\JEDIExportSuccess1
exec perl\RRP\SetupReq\testdef_ijk
exec perl\RRP\RRP-1.30\JEDI\SetupReq\confAbvExp
exec perl\RRP\RRP-1.30\JEDI\JEDIExportSuccess2
exec perl\RRP\SetupReq\testdef_ijk
exec perl\RRP\RRP-1.30\JEDI\SetupReq\confAbvExp
exec perl\RRP\RRP-1.30\JEDI\JEDIExportSuccess3
exec perl\LRP\SetupReq\testird_LRP("LRP")
exec perl\BaseLibs\launch_client("LRP")
exec perl\LRP\LRP-classic-4.14\churrip\chorSingle
exec perl\LRP\BaseLibs\setupLRPMMMTab
exec perl\LRP\BaseLibs\launchMMM
exec perl\LRP\BaseLibs\launchLRPCHURRTA("TYRE")
#PAUSE Expand Churrip tree view & open all nodes
exec perl\LRP\LRP-classic-4.14\Corrugator\multipleSeriesWeb
exec perl\BaseLibs\ShutApp("Self Destruction System")
exec perl\LRP\BaseLibs\close-MMM
exec perl\LRP\SetupReq\testird_LRP("LRP")
exec perl\BaseLibs\launch_client("LRP")
exec perl\LRP\LRP-classic-4.14\churrip\chorSingle
exec perl\LRP\BaseLibs\setupLRPMMMTab
exec perl\LRP\BaseLibs\launchMMM
exec perl\LRP\BaseLibs\launchLRPCHURRTA("TYRE")
#PAUSE Expand Churrip tree view & open all nodes
exec perl\LRP\LRP-classic-4.14\Corrugator\multipleSeriesWeb
exec perl\BaseLibs\ShutApp("Self Destruction System")
exec perl\LRP\BaseLibs\close-MMM
```

I tried searching for my answers over net but wasn't able to find one specific to my needs.

Given File-1 and File-2
Here is what i expect my script to output
(I have listed what output i expect for each line in FILE-1)

```
For line "1.20/abc/this_is_test_1" in FILE-1
Output
exec 1.20/setup/testinit
exec 1.20/abc/this_is_test_1
exec 1.20/abc/this_is_test_1

For line "perl/RRP/RRP-1.30/JEDI/JEDIExportSuccess2" in FILE-1
Output
exec perl/RRP/SetupReq/testdef_ijk
exec perl/RRP/RRP-1.30/JEDI/SetupReq/confAbvExp
exec perl/RRP/RRP-1.30/JEDI/JEDIExportSuccess2

For line "exec perl/RRP/RRP-1.30/JEDI/CommonReq/confAbvExp" in FILE-1
Output
do nothing as there is no line matching this is in FILE-2

For line "perl/LRP/BaseLibs/close-MMM" in FILE-1
Output
exec perl/LRP/SetupReq/testird_LRP("LRP")
exec perl/BaseLibs/launch_client("LRP")
exec perl/LRP/LRP-classic-4.14/churrip/chorSingle
exec perl/LRP/BaseLibs/setupLRPMMMTab
exec perl/LRP/BaseLibs/launchMMM
exec perl/LRP/BaseLibs/launchLRPCHURRTA("TYRE")
#PAUSE Expand Churrip tree view & open all nodes
exec perl/LRP/LRP-classic-4.14/Corrugator/multipleSeriesWeb
exec perl/BaseLibs/ShutApp("Self Destruction System")
exec perl/LRP/BaseLibs/close-MMM    

For line "exec perl/LRP/BaseLibs/launchLRPCHURRTA("TYRE")" in FILE-1
Output
Do nothing as it would generate the same black as line "perl/LRP/BaseLibs/close-MMM" in FILE-1 did

For Line "this/or/that" in FILE-1
Output
Do nothing as there is no line matching this is in FILE-2
```

SO my final output should be similiar (order of blocks doesn't matter) to

```
exec 1.20/setup/testinit
exec 1.20/abc/this_is_test_1
exec 1.20/abc/this_is_test_1

exec perl/RRP/SetupReq/testdef_ijk
exec perl/RRP/RRP-1.30/JEDI/SetupReq/confAbvExp
exec perl/RRP/RRP-1.30/JEDI/JEDIExportSuccess2

exec perl/LRP/SetupReq/testird_LRP("LRP")
exec perl/BaseLibs/launch_client("LRP")
exec perl/LRP/LRP-classic-4.14/churrip/chorSingle
exec perl/LRP/BaseLibs/setupLRPMMMTab
exec perl/LRP/BaseLibs/launchMMM
exec perl/LRP/BaseLibs/launchLRPCHURRTA("TYRE")
#PAUSE Expand Churrip tree view & open all nodes
exec perl/LRP/LRP-classic-4.14/Corrugator/multipleSeriesWeb
exec perl/BaseLibs/ShutApp("Self Destruction System")
exec perl/LRP/BaseLibs/close-MMM
```

It would be really great if anyone can give me some pointers on how to proceed. And yes i forgot to mention, this is not a homework question :-) .

Many thanks

Comment: almost a great question. Consider editing to include block of sample output, given your file1 and file2. Good luck.

Comment: What does `blah blah blah` stand for? Do you always want three lines after each match? Anyway, you could mogrify a single `sed` script from your `file-1` and run just one pass over the big input file.

Comment: @tripleee I have addedd info in the question as to what blah blah blah stands for. There might be any number of lines between lines containing setup keyword. Also can you please give some more insight about what you are suggesting me to do with sed script? I don't think i understood it properly. Many thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks @tripleee and @Jarmund for your suggestions. From your inputs I was finally able to figure out solution of my problem. I got hint from associative arrays to make unique key for each block, so here is what i did

- take file-2 and convert each block into single line

  awk '/[Ss]etup.*[Tt]est/ || /perl/[[:alpha:]]*/[Ss]etup[Rr]eq/{if(b) exit; else b=1}1' file-2 > $TESTSETFILE
  cat $TESTSETFILE | sed ':a;N;$!ba;s/\n//g;s/ //g' >> $SINGLELINEFILE
- Now each line in this file is a unique entry
- after this i use grep for each line in File-1 and find respective block(which is converted into single line) now
- Then i use awk or sort -u to find unique entries in my solution file

Maybe this solution is not best but it is lot faster than the previous one.

Here is my new script

```
FLBATCHLIST=$1
BATCHFILE=$2

TEMPDIR="./tempBatchdir"
rm -rf $TEMPDIR/*
WORKFILE="$TEMPDIR/failedTestList.txt"
CPBATCHFILE="$TEMPDIR/orig.test"
TESTSETFILE="$TEMPDIR/testset.txt"
DIFFFILE="$TEMPDIR/diff.txt"
SINGLELINEFILE="$TEMPDIR/singleline.txt"
TEMPFILE="$TEMPDIR/temp.txt"
#Output
FAILEDBATCH="$TEMPDIR/FailedBatch.test"
LOGFILE="$TEMPDIR/log.txt"

convertSingleLine ()
{
sed -i 's/^[[:space:]]*//;s/[[:space:]]*$//g;/^$/d' $CPBATCHFILE
STATUS=1
while [ $STATUS -ne "0" ]
do
        if [ ! -s $CPBATCHFILE ]; then
                echo "$CPBATCHFILE is empty" >> $LOGFILE
                STATUS=0
        fi
        awk '/[Ss]etup.*[Tt]est/ || /perl\/[[:alpha:]]*\/[Ss]etup[Rr]eq/{if(b) exit; else b=1}1' $CPBATCHFILE > $TESTSETFILE
        cat $TESTSETFILE | sed ':a;N;$!ba;s/\n//g;s/ //g' >> $SINGLELINEFILE
        echo "**" >> $SINGLELINEFILE
        TSTFLLINES=`wc -l < $TESTSETFILE`
        CPBTCHLINES=`wc -l < $CPBATCHFILE`
        DIFF=`expr $CPBTCHLINES - $TSTFLLINES`
        tail -n $DIFF $CPBATCHFILE > $DIFFFILE
        mv $DIFFFILE $CPBATCHFILE
done
}

####STARTS HERE####
mkdir -p $TEMPDIR

sed 's/^[eE][xX][eE][cC]//g;s/^[[:space:]]*//;s/[[:space:]]*$//g;/^$/d' $FLBATCHLIST > $WORKFILE
sed -i 's/\([\/\.\"]\)/\\\1/g' $WORKFILE

cp $BATCHFILE $CPBATCHFILE
convertSingleLine

for fltest in $(cat $WORKFILE)
do
        echo $fltest >> $LOGFILE
        grep "$fltest" $SINGLELINEFILE >> $FAILEDBATCH
        if [ $? -eq "0" ]; then
                echo "TEST FOUND" >> $LOGFILE
        else
                ABSTEST=$(echo $fltest | sed 's/\\//g')
                echo "FATAL ERROR: Test \"$ABSTEST\" not found in $BATCHFILE" | tee -a $LOGFILE
        fi
done

awk '!x[$0]++' $FAILEDBATCH > $TEMPFILE
mv $TEMPFILE $FAILEDBATCH

sed -i "s/exec/\\nexec /g;s/#/\\n#/g" $FAILEDBATCH
sed -i '1d;s/\//\\/g' $FAILEDBATCH
```

Here is the output

```
$ crflbatch file-1 file-2
FATAL ERROR: Test "perl/RRP/RRP-1.30/JEDI/CommonReq/confAbvExp" not found in file-2
FATAL ERROR: Test "this/or/that" not found in file-2

$ cat tempBatchdir/FailedBatch.test
exec 1.20\setup\testinit
exec 1.20\abc\this_is_test_1
exec 1.20\abc\this_is_test_1

exec perl\RRP\SetupReq\testdef_ijk
exec perl\RRP\RRP-1.30\JEDI\SetupReq\confAbvExp
exec perl\RRP\RRP-1.30\JEDI\JEDIExportSuccess2

exec perl\LRP\SetupReq\testird_LRP("LRP")
exec perl\BaseLibs\launch_client("LRP")
exec perl\LRP\LRP-classic-4.14\churrip\chorSingle
exec perl\LRP\BaseLibs\setupLRPMMMTab
exec perl\LRP\BaseLibs\launchMMM
exec perl\LRP\BaseLibs\launchLRPCHURRTA("TYRE")
#PAUSEExpandChurriptreeview&openallnodes
exec perl\LRP\LRP-classic-4.14\Corrugator\multipleSeriesWeb
exec perl\BaseLibs\ShutApp("SelfDestructionSystem")
exec perl\LRP\BaseLibs\close-MMM
$
```

Answer (score 0):

Provided that line order does not matter, you can remove duplicates from a file this way, from th ecommand prompt:

```
sort filename | uniq
```

To find which lines are present in both files, I used a perl script that created a hash (or associative array, if you will). Then i scanned through File A, added each line to the hash, using the line as the key, and setting the value to 1. Then i did the same for File A, but setting the value to 2, and if the key already existed, i added 2 instead. The result would be going through each file only once, and at the end i knew that if the key had a value of 1, it only existed in File A, if it had a value of 2, it existed only in File B, and if it had a value of 3, it existed in both.

**Edit:**
I found some perl code laying around from a project, doing exactly what i described above. In this code, i was only after the differences, but it should be easy to modify it to your needs

```
my %found;
foreach my $item (@qlist) { $found{$item} += 2 };
foreach my $item (@xlist) { $found{$item} += 1 };

foreach my $found (keys(%found))
{
  if    ($found{$found} == 3)
  {
    # It's in both files. Not doing anything.
  }
  elsif ($found{$found} == 2)
  {
    print "$found found in the QC-list, but not the x-list.\n";
  }
  elsif ($found{$found} == 1)
  {
    print "$found found in the x-list, but not the QC-list.\n";
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Jarmund for immediate response. It would have been really easy if I didnt have to care about order of lines. Thats what making it complex, I cant use sort for my help here. I know perl a little, but i would rather like to see first if there is any solution in shell script. thanks

Answer (score 0):

The following assumes that the "setup" line is unique for each block.  We use this line as a key to an associative array which keeps track of which blocks we have already printed.

The first line of script reads the first file into a variable called `regex` which collects the lines we want to match on from the first file (the idiom `NR==FNR` means when the line number of the current file is equal to the line number of all files collected, that is, it is true only when we are reading the first file from the argument list).  The rest of the script is fairly straightforward, I should hope.

```
awk 'NR==FNR { gsub(/\//,"\\/"); regex = regex sep $0; sep = "|" ; next}
    /[Ss]etup/ { label = $0; printing = 0; collected = nl = "" }
    { collected = collected nl $0; nl=RS }
    $0 ~ regex { if(!printed[label]) {
        printed[label] = printing = 1; print collected } }
    printing { print }' File-1 File-2
```

If the "setup" line is not necessarily unique, maybe you can use the value of `collected` as a key.

This should (I hope) be robust against multiple lines from `File-1` matching the same block in `File-2`.

I know I hinted at a `sed` solution in a comment but this turned out to be the sort of problem where `awk` felt more natural.  Of course, it could be done in Perl or Python or what have you just as well.

Comment: Thanks tripleee. it didn't actually solve my problem but gave me valuable suggestion as to how i can proceed :-) . Unfortunately I cannot upvote your answer as I dont have enough reputation.

Comment: i did a quick run of awk solution and i get line "exec perl/RRP/RRP-1.30/JEDI/JEDIExportSuccess1" in output which is not expected. I am not that comfortable with awk so it will take me quite a while to understand what you did above :-). Thanks much